# Range of values which not satisfy an equation?

Tags: sorting, inequalities

Let $$x+5=z\tag1$$

**1.** How can i obtain all the values of $0<x<10$ which don't satisfy the given relation. Edit: of course $x$ and $z$ are positive integers.

**2.** What command should i use to find the first instance and to stop the calculations.

How many ways exist in mathematica to sort out only numbers which don't satisty a given relation.

This may appear straighforward for most of you, but thank you so much for your kind welcome.

Comment: What does $y$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Thank you. Edited. It was a typo error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

```
FindInstance[! (x + 5 == z) && 0 < x < 10, {x, z}, Reals, 10]

(*
{{x -> 638/101, z -> -1}, {x -> 919/101, z -> 106}, 
{x -> 134/101,z -> -36}, {x -> 816/101, z -> -33}, 
{x -> 950/101,z -> 103}, {x -> 642/101, z -> -52},
{x -> 744/101,z -> 79}, {x -> 709/101, z -> 88}, 
{x -> 769/101,z -> -27}, {x -> 713/101, z -> 51}}
*)
```

**addendum**

Only integer solution

```
sol=FindInstance[! (x + 5 == z) && 0 <= x <= 10, {x, z}, Integers,10]
SortBy[sol, (x /. # &)]
(*{{x -> 1, z -> 277}, {x -> 3, z -> -981}, 
{x -> 3,z -> -490}, {x -> 3, z -> 703}, 
{x -> 4, z -> 694}, {x -> 6,z -> 10}, {x -> 6, z -> 386}, 
{x -> 7, z -> -618}, {x -> 8,z -> 14}, {x -> 8, z -> 198}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe should i precise that $x$ and $z$ are positive integers. And i am looking for the smallest vallue of $x$ for the instance.

Comment: Try `sol=FindInstance[! (x + 5 == z) && 0 <= x <= 10, {x, z}, Integers, 10]` and select the instance with smallest x `SortBy[sol, (x /. # &)]`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Huh??? How does this answer your question given your constraint "of course $x$
 and $z$ are positive integers" when none of your $x$ values are integers????

Comment: If $0<x<10$ then $x$ and hence $z$ are integers. @UlrichNeumann didn't noticed that but, his answer over reals remains valuable. And we are grateful for you all.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I gave the right answer in my comment (UlrichNeumann has noticed it after all ;-)) and forgot to modify my answer. Done!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann. Thank you so much